# TypeError when trying to fetch data from CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, typeerror

I am new in `Python`. I have a .csv file named `supermarket.csv.` I am trying to fetch data from the file and store it in a DataFrame object. I am using Jupyter as text editor.

Data the file contains:

> ,Address,City,Country,Employees,ID,Name,State
>   0,3666 21st St,San Francisco,USA,8,1,Madeira,CA 94114
>   1,735 Dolores St,San Francisco,USA,15,2,Bready Shop,CA 94119
>   2,332 Hill St,San Francisco,USA,25,3,Super River,California 94114
>   3,3995 23rd St,San Francisco,USA,10,4,Ben's Shop,CA 94114
>   4,1056 Sanchez St,San Francisco,USA,12,5,Sanchez,California
>   5,551 Alvarado St,San Francisco,USA,20,6,Richvalley,CA 94114

The code I am trying to run:

```
 import pandas    
    df1=pandas.read_csv("supermarkets.csv")    
    df1
```

and its throwing an type error:

```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)         
<ipython-input-123-0000e09242f0> in <module>()         
----> 1 df1=pandas.read_csv("supermarkets.csv")        
----> 2 df1     
     TypeError: 'str' object is not callable        
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I was following a tutorial. In the tutorial it worked fine for the instructor. But whenever I'm trying to run this code getting the same error.

I have also tried for .json and .xlsx file. Both are working fine. Only for read_csv() method getting this error.

Comment: The code you run and the code you show aren't the same. Try restarting your kernel. You probably have badly named variables.

Comment: Thanks. After restarting kernel, its working now as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas    
df1 = pandas.read_csv('supermarkets.csv')    
print df1
```

Comment: 1. When posting an answer, at least make an effort to format your code. 2. How is this different from what OP is doing, apart from the broken indentation which is not the source of the error they get.

Comment: Next time I will do it :)

Answer (score 0):

**Improper Indentation**

Python programs get structured through indentation, i.e. code blocks are defined by their indentation. Okay that's what we expect from any program code, isn't it? Yes, but in the case of Python it's a language requirement not a matter of style. This principle makes it easier to read and understand other people's Python code.

[Read more about Python Indentation](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_blocks.php)